# Where's ActionController::Dispatcher in Rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack, dispatcher

I'm following an example in The Rails 3 way, and when I tried to send a request to dispatcher in the console, with `ActionController::Dispatcher.new.call(env).last.body`

I got

`1.9.3p194 :001 > ActionController::Dispatcher.new.call(env).last.body
NameError: uninitialized constant ActionController::Dispatcher'`

I was using rails 3.2.6, I checked the rails api and found out they removed dispatcher in the ActionController, but the rails guide said:*ActionController::Dispatcher.new is the primary Rack application object of a Rails application. Any Rack compliant web server should be using ActionController::Dispatcher.new object to serve a Rails application.*

I find the v3.0.7 of rails api, the Dispatcher still exist in that version.

So, here are my questions: how can I find the equivalent methods serve as ActionController.Dispatcher.new? and given that my apps work well with rails 3.2.6, which part of rails plays the role as ActionController.Dispatcher now?

Comment: The answer by @bentrevor should be accepted as the anwser

Answer (score 5):

This is what the Rails *edge* guides say about primary Rack application objects:

> ApplicationName::Application is the primary Rack application object of a Rails application. Any Rack compliant web server should be using ApplicationName::Application object to serve a Rails application.

So `ActionController::Dispatcher.new` has just been replaced by `ApplicationName::Application`.  I'm not sure when they made this switch.  This worked for me:

```
Blog::Application.call(env).last.body
```

(The first few lines after `NoMethodError: undefined method 'key?' for nil:NilClass` tell us that the `key?` method is being called in `actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb`.  Working backwards from there, we can see that the variable

```
params = env['action_dispatch.request.path_parameters']
```

is nil when it shouldn't be.  So we can set `env['action_dispatch.request.path_parameters']` in the console, but that leads to another `NoMethodError` on a nil object set in the `initialize` method.  So we could probably fix that by passing in an options hash to `Dispatcher.new`, but it's probably best just to use `ApplicationName::Application`.)

Answer (score 3):

It has been moved to ActionDispatch (actionpack/lib/action_dispatch) and can be found here: **actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb**, class called

```
ActionController::Routing::RouteSet::Dispatcher.new
```

Comment: Thanks,it seems like `ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::Dispatcher.new` also did the trick. however, I got another error `NoMethodError: undefined method 'key?' for nil:NilClass` can't find out why.